# Chrome.storage.sync.get not storing value in local variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
function getBugVal() {
    var bugVal = "";

    chrome.storage.sync.get('bugId', function (obj) {
        console.log(obj.bugId);
        bugVal = obj.bugId;
        console.log(bugVal + "<- val inside get sync");
    });

    console.log(bugVal + "<- val outside get sync");
    return bugVal;
}
```

If I call getBugVal() the return value keeps indicating an **empty string** instead of the actual value from the chrome.storage.sync.get. bugVal is not even saving the string value.

```
console.log(bugVal + "<- val inside get sync");
```

yields the correct value within the inner function call. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. That's how async code works. You'll have to use callbacks. Something like this would probably work.

```
function workWithBugVal(val) {
    // Do stuff
}

function getBugVal(callback) {
    var bugVal = "";

    chrome.storage.sync.get('bugId', function (obj) {
        console.log(obj.bugId);
        bugVal = obj.bugId;
        callback(bugVal);
    });
}

getBugVal(workWithBugVal);
```

Comment: Well they could have left out the word SYNC from storage.sync now, couldn't they?